# how to find digits except trailing zeroes

Tags: permutations

I have came across many questions of permutations and combination but I am confused in these types of questions “how to find last two digits" except trailing zeros in $1000!$

where $!$ represents factorial sign

any ideas would be appreciable.

Comment: Do you mean to say that you _can_ answer "trailing zeros in $1000!$", but other problems are more difficult? Could you give one or two specific examples of a problem that confuses you?

Comment: I didn't get you!

Comment: @ashi, Question: In base $10$, the rightmost non-zero $1^{st}$, $2^{nd}$ and $3^{rd}$ digit of $n!$. 

Note: In base $10$, the rightmost non-zero $1^{st}$ digit of $n!$ is $2, 4, 6,$ or $8$ always.

Comment: @ashi I do not understand your question. I am trying to find out what it is. That is what my previous comment was about.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a brute force way to do it.

Factor $1000!$ as

$2^{998}3^{498}5^{249}...97^{10}$

using primes as bases and the floor-function sum to get the exponents.  Divide out $2^{249}5^{249}$ which represents the terminal zeroes, then multiply out the remaining factors modulo $100$.  For all primes $p$ except $2$ and $5$, $p^{20}\equiv1 \ mod \ 100$.  Have at it!